# Why am I getting AADSTS50126 error when trying to auth to microsoft with http requests?

Tags: http, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm writing console app that will download or upload content to OneDrive and I've registered my app in Azure service. I'm using Username and password for authorization as it should be used by mane other users, not just me. But anyhow I'm getting AADSTS50126 error when i'm sending POST request to microsoft auth services. What am I missing?

And if it matters, I tried not only my app, but also Postman to try to auth. Same result

**EDIT 1**:
I'm sending request to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumer/oauth/v2.0/token
```

And the request body looks like this (but url encoded)

```
grant_type=password&username=*my email*&password=*password*&client_id=*my client id*&client_secret=*secret*
```

I also tried my another account and it errored something like that "this account not in the azure group" or something.

And to note, this is just c++ console app, and i'm using winhttp api.
And the users are supposed to access their own onedrive, not organization's one or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code your trying to use to do the authentication, that error usually means that you trying to use a federated user but your trying to just authentication directly against Azure which isn't allowed. If you use something like the MSAL library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-adfs-support in that instance it will detect that you have a federated user and can do the federated authentication (eg an active ADFS login and SAML assertion).